# Simplex Algorithm (Two-Phase) - Finding pivot entries consistent with the simplex method

Tags: linear-programming, simplex, two-phase-simplex

I'm working through the examples in my professor's class notes, but I can't figure out how to solve this problem:

> **Example:**   In the following standard tableau, mark by * the choices for the pivot entry consistent with the simplex method: (Note
>   last row is the objective function)
>
> $$ 
>      \begin{array}{|ccccc|c|} \hline       x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&x_5&-1&\\ \hline
>        0&1&-2&3&4&2&=-x_6\\  1&1&-2&3&4&0&=-x_7\\  -3&-1& 0&-3&-4&-2&=-x_8\\ \hline  1&1& 2&1&1&-1&\rightarrow max\\ \hline
>      \end{array}  $$
>
> **Solution.**
>
> $$ 
>      \begin{array}{|ccccc|c|} \hline       x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&x_5&-1&\\ \hline
>        0&1&-2&3*&4&2&=-x_6\\  1*&1*&-2&3&4*&0&=-x_7\\  -3&-1& 0&-3*&-4&-2&=-x_8\\ \hline  1&-1& -2&1&1&-1&\rightarrow max\\ \hline
>      \end{array}  $$

I just don't know how these pivots are being identified. I might just be misunderstanding the question, because I thought that each step of the simplex method only had one possible pivot point.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're sure that the solution tableau is *right*?  It's not even feasible nor optimal.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1605269/290189
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
        x_j &     -1 &         \\ \hline
     a_{1j} & b_{1j} &   =-x_6 \\
     a_{2j} & b_{2j} &   =-x_7 \\
     a_{3j} & b_{3j} &   =-x_8 \\ \hline
      \star &  \star & \to \max \\ \hline
  \end{array}
For each $j$, choose $i \in \operatorname{argmin} \left\{\dfrac{b_{rj}}{a_{rj}}:a_{rj}>0,r \in \{1,2,3\}\right\}
$.